# NetSuite: Where can I find the field ID of the Subcustomers List?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

**What is the internal field ID of the subcustomers list?**
I can't seem to locate the internal field ID of the subcustomers list on parent customer records. It's not on the customer record page on the Record Browser, and it's definitely not a custom record or list, so I'm kinda lost. Any help?

For context: I'm writing a script to update the billing address of all child records when the billing address of the parent record has been changed. So I need the field ID of the subcustomers list so I can loop through each record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search the customers where parent is current customer and get the ids of the children customers.

```
nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, ['parent', 'anyof', PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID]);
```

For scripting you can write a user event and in case of user event your PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID would be the current record Id itself which you can get using `nlapiGetRecordId()` in your user event script on parent customer.

For God known reasons, NetSuite is pulling up the PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID record also in the search result, so, better to filter it off with an additional criteria

```
nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, [['parent', 'anyof', PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID], 'and', ['internalid', 'noneof', PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID]])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you once again for helping me out! I knew there was a better way to do this :)

Comment: nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null,[ ['parent', 'anyof', PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID], 'and', ['internalid', 'noneof', PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID]]);

Comment: You were fast! I removed my comment because I thought I had figured it out. Like the Help Center details, I tried making a filters array like this: var filters = [];
     filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('parent', null, 'anyof', parentId);
     filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('parent', null, 'noneof', '@NONE@'); I feel like this worked, what do you think?

Comment: your filter might fail, if the PARENT record itself is child of one, thoughts?

Comment: good point, though I think we might be okay. To play it safe, I think I will use what you've provided. Thanks again!